# IF Statement in eBay API

Tags: php, if-statement, ebay-api

I have a PHP code to use eBay API to get 5 results by keyword.

I want to add an IF condition to show a headline `<h2>List of products</h2>` only if there are results.

```
    // Check to see if the request was successful, else print an error
if ($resp->ack == "Success") {
$results = '';
// If the response was loaded, parse it and build links  

foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
$pic   = $item->galleryPlusPictureURL;
$link  = $item->viewItemURL;
$title = $item->title;
$price = $item->sellingStatus->currentPrice;

// For each SearchResultItem node, build a link and append it to $results
$results .= "<tr><td style=\"text-align: center;\"><img width=\"300\"   src=\"$pic\"></td></tr><tr><td><a href=\"$link\" rel=\"nofollow\">$title</a></td></tr><tr><td style=\"text-align: right;\">".$price." &euro;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div><a href=\"$link\" rel=\"nofollow\"><p class=\"bux\">> Offer</p></a></div></td></tr>";
}
}
// If the response does not indicate 'Success,' print an error
else {
$results  = "<h3>Oops! The request was not successful. Make sure you are  using   a valid ";
$results .= "AppID for the Production environment.</h3>";
}

echo "<table>".$results."</table>";
```

How do I edit the code above in order to show `<h2>List of products</h2>` only if there is at least one result otherwise show nothing?

Comment: Do you want it to be part of the table or just a heading above (outside) the table?

Comment: Headline should be placed outside, before the table. @RST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Check to see if the request was successful, else print an error
if ($resp->ack == "Success") {
    $results = '';
    // If the response was loaded, parse it and build links  

    foreach($resp->searchResult->item as $item) {
        $pic   = $item->galleryPlusPictureURL;
        $link  = $item->viewItemURL;
        $title = $item->title;
        $price = $item->sellingStatus->currentPrice;

       // For each SearchResultItem node, build a link and append it to  $results
        $results .= "<tr><td style=\"text-align: center;\"><img width=\"300\"   src=\"$pic\"></td></tr><tr><td><a href=\"$link\" rel=\"nofollow\">$title</a></td></tr><tr><td style=\"text-align: right;\">".$price." &euro;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div><a href=\"$link\" rel=\"nofollow\"><p class=\"bux\">> Offer</p></a></div></td></tr>";
    }
    if ( ! empty($results) )
        $results = '<h2>List of products</h2>'. $results;
}
// If the response does not indicate 'Success,' print an error
else {
    $results  = "<h3>Oops! The request was not successful. Make sure you are  using   a valid ";
    $results .= "AppID for the Production environment.</h3>";
}

echo "<table>".$results."</table>";
```

Comment: No, using this code the headline is always shown if there is 0 or more items because "Success" means the API request is correct (but it might have 0 results).